# Hiding a vertical layout programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to hide a vertical layout. I currently have a a horizontal layout with two vertical layouts.I wanted to hide one of the vertical layouts(with all its content) on button click. Any suggestions on how I could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inserting vertical layouts directly into your top-level horizontal layout, use container widgets to easily control visibility:

```
// Create your left and right widgets
QWidget* leftWidget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout(leftWidget);
QWidget* rightWidget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout(rightWidget);

// Populate your vertical layouts here ...

QHBoxLayout* horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(parentWidget);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(leftWidget);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(rightWidget);
```

Then, you can simply hide or show `leftWidget` or `rightWidget` to effectively control the visibility of everything in the vertical layouts that you have, without having to hide/show each individual widget.

Answer (score 5):

As @jmk said, you need to use a QWidget. I'll just add that it's very easy to turn an existing horizontal or vertical layout into a widget from Qt Designer by right-clicking on it and selecting Morph Into->QWidget:

[image]

The layout is entirely preserved, but now you can show/hide the layout box because it's an ordinary widget with that layout.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
// l is the layout pointer
for (int i = 0; i != l->count(); ++i) {
  QWidget* w = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(l->itemAt(i));
  if (w != 0) {
    w->setVisible(false); // hides the widget
  }
  else {
    // do some recursive things with the layout
  }
}
```

(Hope it works ;))

The widget is basically invisible.

Comment: An approach like like this might work, except you'll be explicitly setting the visibility for each widget. If some of those widgets were already hidden, then you'll have to be careful when you make them visible again. In this case, it's much simpler to use a parent widget to control visibility.